# how to get data using two where clauses in Laravel 5

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I used this query for getting the data as below:-

```
 $count=join('training','training.id','=','schedule.training_id') 
->where('schedule.training_end_date','<',carbon::now())
->where('schedule.training_id','=','training.id')
->get();
 echo count($count);
```

This query filter where('schedule.training_end_date','<',carbon::now())
statement only so how to get to satisfied both of statement.
I am thankful if anyone help me to solve out this problem

Comment: As I can see you are joining 2 tables. Where is your DB::table('table name ') statement. and please elaborate what issue you have

Comment: My issue is  I have two table training and schedule and schedule have foreign key of is training and i display the data by joining these two table and my specification is to display count expire date with equal to training_id which are given when form is submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count=DB::table('schedule')
->join('training','training.id','=','schedule.training_id') 
->where('schedule.training_end_date','<',carbon::now())
->where('schedule.training_id','=','training.id')
->get();
 echo count($count);
```

I think you missed out this line `DB::table('schedule')`